# Eigenvalues are zero: what is the meaning?

Tags: geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, polygons

I have the following MATLAB code:

```
n = [10, 20, 50, 100];
j = 1;

% Create closed planar polygon
L = linspace(0,2.*pi,n(j)-1);
x = cos(L);
y = sin(L);
x = [x, x(1)]';
y = [y, y(1)]';

% x_hat0 and y_hat0 (first iteration)
x(:,2) = x(:,1) - 1/10 * (sum(x(:,1)));
y(:,2) = y(:,1) - 1/10 * (sum(y(:,1)));
x_pol(:,2) = x(:,2) / norm(x(:,2)); % Normalized vectors
y_pol(:,2) = y(:,2) / norm(y(:,2));

% Compute new points (produces square matrices so that I can compute
% eig(x), eig(y)
for k=2:n(j)-1
 for i=1:(n(j)-1)
    x(i,k+1) = (x(i,k) + x(i+1,k))/2;
    y(i,k+1) = (y(i,k) + y(i+1,k))/2;
end
x(end,k+1) = x(1,k+1);
y(end,k+1) = y(1,k+1);
x_pol(:,k+1) = x(:,k+1) / norm(x(:,k+1));
y_pol(:,k+1) = y(:,k+1) / norm(y(:,k+1));
end
```

It basically creates a sequence of new polygons by taking the new vertices as the middle point of the previous ones: given two column vectors of x and y coordinates (starting values), it takes the middle point of each side and creates a new polygon with vertices being these new x and y coordinates. I can see that if you keep doing this, you will end up with the center of mass of the polygon. I also noticed, by chance, that the eigenvalues (of the matrices of coordinates, with each column being the x or y coordinates of one polygon) keep decreasing until they reach the value zero. Is this a coincidence? Is there a (hidden) property of this iterative process? Where can I learn more?

[Plot of the polygons](https://usi365-my.sharepoint.com/personal/fabbrl_usi_ch/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=qq4eY%2BvJoSbhzwnviDDWeiR5WdjldhCXKivXfCvY0WY%3D&docid=1f2887a6924144cb796a907acab93fbc7&rev=1)

[Normalized coordinates](https://usi365-my.sharepoint.com/personal/fabbrl_usi_ch/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=7nPOLk%2BSNWDibmnLzeW%2B%2BkJorsAlL%2BKhiGw6InGlqNw%3D&docid=1026ef95779dd4eceb379bc8571be5922&rev=1)

[Real part of eigenvalues of y coordinates matrix](https://usi365-my.sharepoint.com/personal/fabbrl_usi_ch/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=V3z13%2BqkOn0a7TlIufdGNi%2BuhTixoERDdd89rdbvmlE%3D&docid=146d7a35ebaad456884d2ba9c00498b8c&rev=1)

Lorenzo

Comment: You should describe precisely in words what that code does: your description «it basically…» is not good enough to know what it does (of what matrix of what coordinates in what order are you talking about?, etc) You should not expect people to read the code and deduce what it does… I tried, and it seems to be even morfe obscure than your description!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ....even assuming that some of us have the slightest idea of what that thing does...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you, I added more details.

Answer (score 2):

For all the interested people, this is a very nice publication which explains everything in detail:

[From Random Polygon to Ellipse: An Eigenanalysis](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/EllipsePoly.pdf)

Comment: Nice reference [+1]. An important set of keywords on the subject is "Curve Shortening flow". See the very nice article in American Mathematical Monthly (April 2007) "Semidiscrete Geometric Flows of Polygons
By: Bennett Chow and David Glickenstein"

Comment: Behind the AMM article:1) differential sytems 2) a discrete version of the "heat equation" (another very important group of keywords). D. Glickenstein works on heat equation under different disguises. See for example (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506182)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. But it's too advanced for me! A first year master student in computational science with a Bachelor in Biology... But it's really nice and interesting, especially the part regarding the heat equation. I will put it in the reading list.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the coordinates of the polygon vertices approach the centroid $G=(x_G,y_G)$. That means your square matrix for the $x$ coordinates, for instance, will approach a $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are all equal to $x_G$. Such a matrix can have as eigenvalues only $0$ and $nx_G$ (apparently you missed the latter for some reason).